# Search file for string with variable content

Tags: command-line, grep, search

Searching a file for a string is fairly straight forward, usually involving the  `cat *** | grep ***` command. Whilst this is appropriate in most instances, I am trying to search a file for a string for which a substring will be randomised.

To elaborate, the command I am looking for would identify the string by the 2 substrings `Threat:` and `detected`, however the single word which would exist between those 2 words, would be randomised, e.g. `Threat: 'unimportant_garbage' detected`.

Answer (score 3):

Grep can do this

```
grep 'Threat:.*detected'
```